# Problema con iterator en Java 8.2

Tags: java, arraylist

hago una consulta. Primero paso el codigo de mi pequeño programa de ejercicios

```
public class Paciente {

    private int nroPaciente;
    private int telefono;
    private String nombre;

    public Paciente(int tel, String nom){

        this.telefono=tel;
        this.nombre=nom;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){

           this.nombre=nombre;

    }

    public int getTelefono(){

        return this.telefono;
    }

}

public class Turno {
    private String dia;
    private String hora;
    private int nroConsultorio;
    private int nroPaciente;

    public Turno(String dia, String hora, int nroCons, int nroPac ){

        this.dia=dia;
        this.hora=hora;
        this.nroConsultorio= nroCons;
        this.nroPaciente= nroPac;

    }

    public String getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public String getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public int getNroConsultorio() {
        return nroConsultorio;
    }

    public int getNroPaciente() {
        return nroPaciente;
    }

    public void setDia(String dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public void setHora(String hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public void setNroConsultorio(int nroConsultorio) {
        this.nroConsultorio = nroConsultorio;
    }

    public void setNroPaciente(int nroPaciente) {
        this.nroPaciente = nroPaciente;
    }

    public Boolean esMismoDia(String diaConsultado){

        Boolean mismoDia=false;

        if(this.dia.equals(diaConsultado)){
            mismoDia=true;
        }

        return mismoDia;

    }
}


public class Consultorio {
    private int nroConsultorio;
    private String medico;
    private List<Turno> turnos;

    public Consultorio(int nroCons, String med){

        this.nroConsultorio=nroCons;
        this.medico=med;
        this.turnos= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void agregarTurno(String dia, String hora, int nroPaciente){

        Turno turno = new Turno(dia, hora, this.nroConsultorio, nroPaciente);

        turnos.add(turno);

    }

   /*SE INGRESA UNA FECHA EN LA QUE SE PINTARA EL CONSULTORIO,
   SI ES NA FECHA DE ALGUN TURNO GRADADO ESTE SE ELIMINARA DE LA LISTA*/

    public void sePinta(String fechaPintura){

        Iterator<Turno> itTurnos= this.turnos.iterator();

        while(itTurnos.hasNext()){

            Turno t = itTurnos.next();

            if(t.esMismoDia(fechaPintura)){
                itTurnos.remove();
            }

        }

    }

    public List<Turno> getTurnos() {
        return turnos;
    }

}

public class Ejercicio_Final_13_Consultorio {

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
   */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO code application logic here

       Consultorio c= new Consultorio(1, "German");

       c.agregarTurno("10/05/2019", "12:00", 1);
       c.agregarTurno("11/05/2019", "12:00", 2);
       c.agregarTurno("12/05/2019", "12:00", 3);



       Iterator<Turno> itTurnos = c.getTurnos().iterator();

    //Funcion para pasar la fecha en la que se pintara el consultorio
    //para que se eliminen los turnos de dicha fecha

       c.sePinta("10/05/2019");


    //MOSTRAR DIAS CARGADOS

       while(itTurnos.hasNext()){

           Turno t = itTurnos.next();
           System.out.println("Consultorio: "+t.getNroConsultorio());
           System.out.println("Paciente: "+t.getNroPaciente());
           System.out.println("Dia: "+t.getDia());
           System.out.println("Hora: "+t.getHora());
       }

    }

}
```

Bueno, es larguito, pero queria que quede claro. Cuando elimino un objeto de la lista con el iterator ,y luego, quiero recorrerlo con otro iterator para mostrar el resultado luego de la eliminacion anterior, me arroja este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
>       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
>       at ejercicio_final_13_consultorio.Ejercicio_Final_13_Consultorio.main(Ejercicio_Final_13_Consultorio.java:42)
>   C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Pero cuando lo recorro con el siguiente foreach, no:

```
    for(Turno t : c.getTurnos()){

        System.out.println(t.getDia());

    }
```

Main

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Consultorio c= new Consultorio(1, "German");

    c.agregarTurno("10/05/2019", "12:00", 1);
    c.agregarTurno("11/05/2019", "12:00", 2);
    c.agregarTurno("12/05/2019", "12:00", 3);



    Iterator<Turno> itTurnos = c.getTurnos().iterator();

    //Funcion para pasar la fecha en la que se pintara el consultorio
    //para que se eliminen los turnos de dicha fecha

    c.sePinta("10/05/2019");


    //MOSTRAR DIAS CARGADOS

     while(itTurnos.hasNext()){

        Turno t = itTurnos.next();
        System.out.println("Consultorio: "+t.getNroConsultorio());
        System.out.println("Paciente: "+t.getNroPaciente());
        System.out.println("Dia: "+t.getDia());
        System.out.println("Hora: "+t.getHora());
     }

  }
```

... quiero probar con el iterator, ya supongo que se ha dejado de usar por el foreach, pero igual tengo esta duda que me esta matando.

Comment: Aclaro que cuando lo leo con el while antes de eliminar, si me muestra todo lo que pido por consola. El problema es que no puedo hacer lo mismo luego de eliminar algo de la lista

Comment: Hola GALS puedes poner tu método main() por favor.

Comment: @AlvaroC. ahi lo modifique, perdon, hice un lio tremendo jaja

Comment: El ciclo while que armaste si va con el iterador. El problema es que el elemento a eliminar lo debes borrar de la lista original y no del iterador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no lo estoy viendo mal, en un mismo momento tienes dos iteradores sobre el mismo objeto. Paso por paso:

- La clase Consultorio tiene un ArrayList de *turnos*
- Creas un primer iterador sobre el array con la instrucción:
  `Iterator<Turno> itTurnos = c.getTurnos().iterator();`
- Inmediatamente después, llamas al método *sePinta*, el cual **crea un segundo iterador sobre el mismo objeto**, es decir, el ArrayList de turnos del objeto consultorio.
- En este momento tienes **dos iteradores sobre el mismo ArrayList**. Este método utiliza el iterador para **modificar el array**. Hasta aquí no has tenido problemas porque ningún otro iterador ha recorrido la lista tras las modificaciones, por lo que no te devuelve ningún error.
- Seguidamente quieres recorrer el mismo ArrayList (fíjate que en todo momento los iteradores están creados sobre el mismo objeto), **con el primer iterador que has creado**, pero ahora está el problema de que la lista se ha modificado con otro iterador externo, por lo que las condiciones sobre las que se crearon el primer iterador ya no son las mismas, es decir, has modificado desde un *"proceso"* externo la lista por lo que el iterador ya no puede garantizar la integridad de su funcionamiento y genera esa excepción. Pongo proceso entre comillas porque, aunque efectivamente no son dos hilos independientes, internamente hablando ha detectado que el array ha sido modificado de manera "concurrente" o paralela y este tipo de iteradores no está diseñado para ello.

Sobre tu código tienes una solución muy sencilla (pero cuestionable): genera el iterador *itTurnos* después de haber llamado al método *sePinta*. De este modo el array ya habrá sido modificado previamente.

Lo ideal es que tengas un único iterador en cada momento, de manera que no tengas que estar pendiente de este tipo de cosas.

La modificación concurrente de listas (del tipo que sean) es problemático con o sin iteradores. Incluso un simple array puede dar problemas con uso concurrente. Por poner un caso extremo: supon que durante el recorrido de un bucle for haces una llamada a un método que modifica elimina un objeto al que hace referencia al array. Cuando vuelves a tu bucle y llegas a esa posición resulta que el objeto no existe y ahora es null, ya puedes tener problemas. O sobre una lista enlazada añades un elemento mientras la recorres; ese elemento podría quedar fuera, por lo que el resultado sería incierto. Son sólo ejemplos que, obviamente tienen su solución, pero es para que te hagas una idea del problema de recorrer y modificar una colección desde lugares diferentes de manera simultanea.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html